# Speed up Adobe Dreamweaver key rate for OSX

Tags: macos, performance, keyboard, adobe, dreamweaver

**Does anyone know of any way to speed up the keyrate in Adobe Dreamweaver.**

I'm currently using CC at the moment and do a lot of coding and to select text it's as slow as the fastest of all snails which hinders my workflow and productivity. I simply need it to be faster than what it is.

I already have a program installed on my OSX machine that speeds up the keys to my super fast liking [Karabiner](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/) A.K.A keyremap4macbook which has no effect on the Dreamweaver software. It does work for other text editors though.

I have also tried termianal commands but yeah, to no effect either.

Any help on the matter would be just awesome.

Answer (score 1):

It is not the mac, it is dreamweaver itself - It is just very slow and laggy as a program.
I am having massive slowdown issues with CC2015 on a 32gb mac i7.
It is the Live and Design view of dreamweaver that causes the issues I think.

Comment: I usually only use code view and have 'related files' switched off in the settings. I remember around say 2005, I use to do all my design work on a Mac then transport it to a windows based machine to do coding in DW because the mac version would always crash on weigh down the computer. Oh well!

Answer (score 1):

This sometimes improves the speed. Taken from [forums.adobe.com](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1292120?tstart=0):

1. Edit -> Preferences -> Code Hints -> Disable description tooltips
2. Edit -> Preferences -> Highlighting -> Untick both Live Data Untranslated and Translated
3. Edit -> Preferences -> Sync Settings -> Untick all in sync settings

Answer (score -1):

umm...
You could try booting windows 10 with bootcamp